# IndexError in Python with Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have following code that keeps giving me an `IndexError` and I simply can't see why:

```
mainMenu = np.array(['Load new data', 
                 'Check for data errors', 
                 'Generate plots', 
                 'Display list of grades', 
                 'Quit'])

if choice == 2 or choice == 3 or choice == 4:
    print("Please load data before you {:s}".format(mainMenu[choice-1]))
    continue
```

The last part is what's giving the error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Can anyone see what the problem is here?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the TraceBack error as well?

Comment: its strange to see used numpy array for options, you can use list also

Comment: Why is mainMenu an array instead of a list?

Comment: That's because I use mainMenu in another function that uses arrays, so my thought was that it's more compatible using arrays in both scenarios.
Regardless a list should also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it seems when you define your `choice` variable it is not an integer. For instance it is declared as `choice = 4.0` rather than `choice=4`
I would suggest the following change

```
 if choice == 2 or choice == 3 or choice == 4:
       print("Please load data before you {:s}".format(mainMenu[int(choice)-1]))
continue
```

Comment: python supports dynamic type , so no need to cast to int

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seemed to fix the problem!

Comment: @Roushan yes you are right, but here `choice` is being used as a literal index not necessarily a python variable, that is why, even if  value of the variable `choice = 4.00`, `choice ==4` evaluates as `True` but if the same variable if used as index, python doesnt know what you want it to be

Comment: ok, they why it executing `choice == 2 or choice == 3 or choice == 4:` as they also ints